# PyCharm refuses to make an Anaconda environment no matter what

Tags: python, pycharm, conda

I am trying to use a conda interpreter in PyCharm, but for some reason it is not working. I just tell it to make new environment or use the current environment, and it loads up for a bit then stops without even an error code. You can see the screen that shows up in the image below.

[image: this is what i get when making a new or using old environment]

I have tried installing and uninstalling PyCharm and Anaconda. I also tried to make a new environment and specified it was python 3.9 and still nothing worked. Also I can make a new environment if I set administrative privileges and make one by project, but those environments are not being saved and can not be used by other projects.

The most valid method for me was to name an empty directory `my environment` and create an new environment through there, making the environment available for all projects, however this is very non-intuitive.

I can make a new environment by just making one automatically for a project, however I can not add an existing conda interpreter when I am in the project by using the add local interpreter feature.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit tricky but you should check the radio button saying *Previously configured interpreter*, somewhere around the middle of the screen, see here:

[image: Environment]

From that part of your screen, you should normally be able to select some of the prexisting environments you have created and reuse them for your project.

**NOTE:** The word *interpreter* here, is associated with the environment. Each environment has its own interpreter.

Your interpreter should normally be available, in the *status bar* of your PyCharm window, but for some reason it does not appear in your case. In general you can see more on that subject in the [official documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#modify_interpreter).

Comment: thanks , i know it is a weird error , atleast i have found a workaround for now